# Switching Character View

Tags: broken-age

My question involves minor spoilers.

So I decided to play through Act 1 of Broken Age again before jumping into Act 2. I played all the way through Vella's side of the story first and now I'm playing through Shay's.

The problem is that I decided to change over to Vella's view after I had beaten it. The game shows her lying on the beach, knocked out. Now I can't switch back to Shay. I've tried bringing the inventory menu up. That way, I could click on the Shay button to go back to his story. Unfortunately, it won't appear. What's odd is the fact that that the mouse changes to a hand (as if I can interact with a menu item) when I hover over the area the character switch button *should be*, even though the menu doesn't appear. Clicking when the cursor is a hand does nothing.

So am I missing something? Or is this a glitch?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a glitch that just started happening after Act 2 was released.  [It will be fixed in the next update](http://www.doublefine.com/forums/viewreply/382069/).

In the meantime, the suggested [workaround from the developer](http://steamcommunity.com/app/232790/discussions/0/620712364023297994/) is to exit the game, launch it again and choose continue game.  This should revert you back to Shay.

If that doesn't work, a community member has given these instructions that users are reporting as working:

> For anyone else with this issue on PC / MAC / Linux you can mess with the .sav files to get back to where you were.
>
> On Steam mine are in:
> /path/to/steam/steamapps/common/Broken Age/saves
>
> 1. Rename slot_.sav to slot_.bak as a backup
> 2. Copy slot_.prev
> 3. Rename that to slot_.sav
> 4. Go back into Broken Age
> 5. Choose “Load game” and click on your slot (Don’t continue!)
>
> That should put you back as Shay from before you decided to check up on Vella.

Comment: Copying the previous save and renaming it as the current save worked. Thank you.